# G28 ignoring Z-Probe X/Y Offsets

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, z-probe, 3dtouch, skr-v1.3

I recently installed a SKR 1.3 Board with a 3DTouch-Probe on my Creality Ender 3 Pro. 
The probe works, `G29` does its magic, but:

If i issue a plain `G28`, the hotend first homes X and Y like before the Z-probe. 
The probe is now next to, not above, the bed.
As the next step, the printer is supposed to home the Z-axis. The probe deploys and Z starts to lower until it smashes into the bed, because the probe misses the bed (if I don't stop it, that is).

I configured X/Y offsets for the probe, but they don't seem to be honored when performing the `G28` code.

If I home X/Y "manually" with `G28 X Y`, move the hotend with like `G1 X45 Y10`, then home Z with `G28 Z` it works fine.

What did I miss? Is this intended behaviour & the user has to take care never to issue a plain `G28`?!

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the constant `Z_SAFE_HOMING` (like: `#define Z_SAFE_HOMING`) in your [printer configuration file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) (if you're using Marlin firmware that is). This will move the nozzle to the middle of the plate prior to lowering the nozzle by default:

```
#if ENABLED(Z_SAFE_HOMING)
  #define Z_SAFE_HOMING_X_POINT ((X_BED_SIZE) / 2)    // X point for Z homing when homing all axes (G28).
  #define Z_SAFE_HOMING_Y_POINT ((Y_BED_SIZE) / 2)    // Y point for Z homing when homing all axes (G28).
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Z Safe Homing` to avoid homing with a Z probe outside the bed area

According to Marlin firmware with this feature enabled:

- Allow Z homing only after X and Y homing AND stepper drivers still
  enabled.
- If stepper drivers time out, it will need X and Y homing again before Z homing.
- Move the Z probe (or nozzle) to a defined XY point before Z Homing when homing all axes (G28).
- Prevent Z homing when the Z probe is outside the bed area.

To Enable Z SAFE HOMING, In the `configuration.h` file search (Ctrl+F) for `#define Z_SAFE_HOMING`. By default, it will be disabled to enable it just uncomment 
the line

[image]